# Adobe illustrator 3D isometric rotate not working well

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics, 3d

I am trying to create a perfect cube in Illustrator by creating 3 squares, and rotating them using Effect > 3D > Rotate.

However, the rotate function doesn't seem to work. It creates imperfect rotations and in the end the faces do not match up perfectly.

For instance look at this screenshot (zoom to actual size to see the defect well). The way I did this is create a square using the rectangle tool and holding the shift key, and then rotating it to isometric left. You can clearly see though that it's not rotated perfectly -- the left side especially is not perfectly vertical as it should be.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't really understand the reason for the migration, and I haven't used that tool in Illustrator, you may be able to have better success exporting from Sketchup. Sketch up offers both isometric and perspective rendering, and you can export directly to vector PDF, which you can open in Illustrator.

Sorry I don't have more to offer about that tool in Illustrator.